# Netbeans .form instead of GUI editor

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, editor

I have a netbeans project in 7.0.1 and I have been using the GUI editor that is built in. It was working great! However this morning when I opened up the project instead of showing in the GUI editor it shows FILENAME.form

I was wondering if anyone knew how to get the project back to using the GUI editor instead of the source .form files.

Answer (score 0):

Chack that the "GUI Builder" plugin is both Installed and Activated.